# Floating type value in ATMega8

Tags: c, calculator, microcontroller, avr, atmega

My Microcontroller doesn't process floating type values so how can I do operations on floating type values using int?

Like I have a value stored in a register a=5
now I want to multiply it with 0.65 and store the result in another register c?
How do I do it?
on using int it solves leaving the fractional value aside while using a float it displays a "?"

Comment: Depending on the compiler you use, it may have floating point handling even if the target CPU doesn't.

Comment: Why doesn't it support it?

Comment: I need to extract the value after "." only I will use it as an integer.. tell me a way to do this??
Suppose I am entering a random number by keypad say abcd.efgh
now I want the efgh only.. How do I use it??

Comment: You need to store the characters and convert it into an integer or floating point number. ATMega* supports floating point arithmetic. Convert it into a character array and use the `atof` function

Comment: This problem has been solved thanx all..

Please move to the new problem :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506198/how-to-store-a-number-in-decimal-format-in-avr

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing multiple problems:

first: even if your target controller does not contain a floating point unit (FPU) the calculations can be done with SW libries.
Usage of this libs usally happens automaticly. and you can do calculations in float.
these libraries are relativly huge in codesize and execution speed. even if you only add simple float arithmetics you will notice a huge increment in code size.

the second problem is the output via the printf-routines. Since floating port support is nomaly not needed, it is striped to save code size. you can explicitly activate it by adding the libraries libprintf_flt.a libm.a and use the linker options -Wl,-u,vfprintf

alternativly you can use the ftoa function.